# how many sequences consisting of $\lbrace 0,1, ..., q\rbrace$ must contain $[..10..]$ or $[..20..]$ or ... $[..(q-1)0..]$ but not necessary $[..q0..]

Tags: probability, combinatorics

How do we solve combinatorial question

How many sequences consisting of $\lbrace 0,1, ..., q\rbrace$ of length $n$ must contain $[..00..]$ or $[..10..]$ or ... $[..(q-1)0..]$ but not necessary $[..q0..]$

For example

> If $q =3$ and $n=4$ then $[1020]$ counted because it contain 10 but not  $[1230]$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the sequences into several groups A,B,C,...
Let A contain $A_n$ sequences of length $n$.
If you choose the right groups, you can work out $A_{k+1}$ in terms of $A_k,B_k,C_k,...$
Once you have recursions, you can solve them to find $A_n,B_n,C_n,...$
If you choose the right groups, you can use $A_n,...$ to answer your question.

Comment: I'm really sorry. My specialty is coding theory I don't know a lot about combinations. Can you please give more details?